algebraic problem
If we have $(x^5 - \frac{1}{x^5} = \sqrt{7}) $ then find value of $ (x^{35} - \frac{1}{x^{35}})$?
Options are:
A $\quad(789\,\sqrt{7})$
B $\quad (790\,\sqrt{7})$
C $\quad (791\,\sqrt{7})$
D $\quad(792\,\sqrt{7})$
Here my approach is I can do it with binomial expansion?
So first of all I tried to solve the question with squaring....(\left(x^5 - \frac{1}{x^5}\right)^2 = \sqrt{7}), (\left(x^5\right)^2 - \left(\frac{1}{x^5}\right)^2 - 2 = x^{10} + \frac{1}{x^{10}} = 9)
(x^5 + \frac{1}{x^5} = \sqrt{11})
After that step we want (x^{35}) so (x^{10} - \frac{1}{x^{10}} = \sqrt{11})
(x^{20} + \frac{1}{x^{20}})
Cubic term will be (\left(x^{30} - \frac{1}{x^{30}} - 3\sqrt{11}\right) = 11\sqrt{11})
(x^{30} - \frac{1}{x^{30}} = 14\sqrt{11})
we have (x^5 + \frac{1}{x^5} = \sqrt{11})
(x^{35} - \frac{1}{x^{25}} + x^{25} - \frac{1}{\frac{1}{x^{35}}} = 14 \times 11)
(x^{35} - \frac{1}{x^{35}} = 154 - \left(x^{25} - \frac{1}{x^{25}}\right)) i am sorry guys I don't know why latex failure. I only used online site for it. I am adding a picture with my work

Hint:  start by computing $x^{10}-\frac 1{x^{10}}$.  Note that the $x^5$ part is not really relevant...you might as well let $z=x^5$ so you are being asked to compute $z^7-\frac 1{z^7}$.

It might be easier to compute $x^{15}-\frac1{x^{15}}$

The fact that $x^5$ and $\frac{1}{x^5}$ gives an integer after multiplication suggests to raise the initial equation to the second power:
$$(x^5 - \frac{1}{x^5})^2 = x^{10} + \frac{1}{x^{10}} - 2$$
$$x^{10} + \frac{1}{x^{10}} = 7 + 2 = 9$$
Then you can take the third power of the obtained equation. The key idea is to get the power $30$, because $30+5=35$
$$(x^{10} + \frac{1}{x^{10}})^3 = x^{30} + \frac{1}{x^{30}} + 3 \cdot x^{10} + 3 \cdot \frac{1}{x^{10}}$$
$$x^{30} + \frac{1}{x^{30}} = 9^3 - 3 \cdot 9 = 729 - 27 = 702$$
At this moment, you should multiply this equation by the initial one:
$$(x^5 - \frac{1}{x^5})(x^{30} + \frac{1}{x^{30}}) = x^{35} - \frac{1}{x^{35}} - (x^{25} - \frac{1}{x^{25}})$$
$$x^{35} - \frac{1}{x^{35}} - (x^{25} - \frac{1}{x^{25}}) = 702 \sqrt{7}$$
Now you have almost finished. You should repeat this reasoning to compute $x^{25} - \frac{1}{x^{25}}$.
$$(x^{10} + \frac{1}{x^{10}})^2 = x^{20} + \frac{1}{x^{20}} + 2$$
$$x^{20} + \frac{1}{x^{20}} = 9^2 - 2 = 81 - 2 = 79$$
$$(x^5 - \frac{1}{x^5})(x^{20} + \frac{1}{x^{20}}) = x^{25} - \frac{1}{x^{25}} -( x^{15} - \frac{1}{x^{15}})$$
And again...
$$(x^5 - \frac{1}{x^5})(x^{10} + \frac{1}{x^{10}}) = x^{15} -\frac{1}{x^{15}} - (x^{5} - \frac{1}{x^{5}})$$
$$x^{15} -\frac{1}{x^{15}} = 9 \sqrt{7} + \sqrt{7} = 10 \sqrt{7}$$
Getting things together:
$$x^{25} - \frac{1}{x^{25}} = 79 \sqrt{7} + 10 \sqrt{7} = 89 \sqrt{7}$$
$$x^{35} - \frac{1}{x^{35}} = 702 \sqrt{7} + 89 \sqrt{7} = 791 \sqrt{7}$$
So, the final answer is C or $791 \sqrt{7}$.

I'm not sure what improvements should I do in it?  I can't ask any question

I'm sorry. I am leaving the community. I only here for asking and learning. The way stopping people just for one inappropriate question is very shameful for me. But I will use MSE forevers and learnt from it
